# making web crawler want to extract the images in url

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-crawler

i want to make web crawler that extract title ,description ,keywords and images from any given url..after extraction i want to save in database... my code does not work for images... any help will be appreciated

```
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var title = $('head title').text();
    var keywords = $('head meta[name=keywords]').attr('content');
    var desc = $('head meta[name=description]').attr('content');
    var links = $('a');
    var img= $('img').attr('content')
    console.log('Crawling "%s" | %s',title,this.url);
    async.map(links.map(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(href && href != self._url && !(/^#(\w)+/.test(href)) && !util.imageRegexp.test(href)){
         if(util.isExternal(href)){
         return 'INSERT INTO `queue` SET `id` = \''+util.id()+'\', `url` = '+self.conn.escape(href)+', `from` = '+self.conn.escape(from);
          console.log("self.conn.escape" + self.conn.escape)
          }
          else {
          return 'INSERT INTO `queue` SET `id` = \''+util.id()+'\', `url` = '+self.conn.escape(util.resolveRelativeURL(href,self._url))+', `from` = '+self.conn.escape(from);
          }
          }
          return false;
         }).filter(function(el){
        return !!el;
        })
        ,this.conn.query.bind(this.conn),function(e,result){
        if(e){
        console.log('Error writing queue.');
        console.log(e);
        }
        });
    this.conn.query('INSERT INTO `websites` SET ?',{
        id:util.id(),
        url:this.url,
        from:from,
        title:title,
        keywords:keywords || '',
        img:img || '',

        desc:desc || ''
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `$('img').attr('content')` you want to download the image itself as a file, that won't work as the image data itself is a separate resource from the HTML, which simply identifies the image's URL. So you'll need to make an HTTP GET request for the image by its `src` attribute value and save that as a file. Node's core http client library will work, as will npm modules such as `request` or `superagent`.